# particle from mesh animation

Tags: particles

hi I would like to know how to avoid emmiting particles from center of mesh when mesh dissappearing.
and addition, can know why original mesh animation and exported animation has different particle emmit phase?

[image]

(this is the start of boolean animation ↓）
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/8aefd7b789bf4205a5a1d6219d14673e　　　this is the blend file thank you.

Comment: so it looks like it's the Boolean that makes it fail? I don't know if it's fixable but you could stop the emission at frame 30 so that it stops before the problem

Comment: thank you  I will